# How i can save bitmap to internal storage?

Tags: android, image, android-internal-storage

In here i want to save my autogenerate qrcode to my internal memory.but, i can't save my image

i already try much code but from base64string to bitmap. but, still i can't save my image.

this is my confirmation.java

```
private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 200;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_confirmasi);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    },REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
    if(PendaftaranDokter.message == "null") {
        Date todayDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy");
        String todayString = formatter.format(todayDate);
        msgcin.setText(todayString);
        NoAntrian.setText("xxxxx");
        if(PendaftaranDokterAfterPoli.tgljanjian1.equals(todayString)) {
            //new MedNo(Login.username1).execute();
            new Regno(PendaftaranDokterAfterPoli.medno).execute();
            msgcin.setText("Registrasi");
            NoAntrian.setText("xxxxx");
        }
        else {
            //new MedNo(Login.username1).execute();
            new AppNo(PendaftaranDokterAfterPoli.medno).execute();
            msgcin.setText("Appointment");
            NoAntrian.setText("-");
        }

        medno.setText(PendaftaranDokterAfterPoli.medno);
        namadokter.setText(PendaftaranDokterAfterPoli.parname1);
        politujuan.setText(PendaftaranPoli.servname1);

        try {
            String date = PendaftaranDokterAfterPoli.tgljanjian1;
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy");
            Date newDate = format.parse(date);
            format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");
            String date1 = format.format(newDate);
            tanggal.setText(date1);
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(Confirmasi.this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Date todayDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy");
        String todayString = formatter.format(todayDate);
            if (PendaftaranDokter.tgljanjian.equals(todayString)) {
                //new MedNo(Login.username1).execute();
                new Regno(PendaftaranDokter.medno).execute();
                msgcin.setText("Registrasi");
                NoAntrian.setText("xxxx");
            } else {
                //new MedNo(Login.username1).execute();
                new AppNo(PendaftaranDokter.medno).execute();
                msgcin.setText("Appointment");
                NoAntrian.setText("-");
            }

        medno.setText(PendaftaranDokter.medno);
        namadokter.setText(PendaftaranDokter.parname);
        politujuan.setText(PendaftaranDokter.servname);

        try {
            String date = PendaftaranDokter.tgljanjian;
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy");
            Date newDate = format.parse(date);
            format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");
            String date1 = format.format(newDate);
            tanggal.setText(date1);
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(Confirmasi.this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    ok = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ok);
    ok.setImageResource(R.drawable.confirmimage);
    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            OpenMainMenu();
        }
    });
}

private  File getOutputMediaFile(){
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/Android/data/"
            + getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
            + "/Files");

    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            return null;
        }
    }
    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmm").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    String mImageName="MI_"+ timeStamp +".jpg";
    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + mImageName);
    return mediaFile;
}

private void storeImage(Bitmap image) {
    File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
    if (pictureFile == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");// e.getMessage());
        return;
    }
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

class Regno extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    private String medno;
    public Regno(String medno) {
        this.medno = medno;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        CallSoap cs = new CallSoap();
        String medno1 = cs.RegNo(medno);
        return medno1;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        MultiFormatWriter multiFormatWriter = new MultiFormatWriter();
        try {
            BitMatrix bitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode(s, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 200, 200);
            BarcodeEncoder barcodeEncoder = new BarcodeEncoder();
            Bitmap bitmap = barcodeEncoder.createBitmap(bitMatrix);
            img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            storeImage(bitmap);
            //saveToInternalStorage(bitmap);
        } catch (WriterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        number.setText(s);
    }
}

class AppNo extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    private String medno;
    public AppNo(String medno) {
        this.medno = medno;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        CallSoap cs = new CallSoap();
        String medno1 = cs.AppointNo(medno);
        return medno1;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        MultiFormatWriter multiFormatWriter = new MultiFormatWriter();
        try {
            BitMatrix bitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode(s, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 100, 100);
            BarcodeEncoder barcodeEncoder = new BarcodeEncoder();
            Bitmap bitmap = barcodeEncoder.createBitmap(bitMatrix);
            img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            storeImage(bitmap);
        } catch (WriterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

in here i already get bitmap of qrcode and i want to save qrcode to my internal mobile storage

Comment: Add `LogCat` data please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` in AndroidManifest file ?

**UPDATE**:
if you want to save to internal storage, you can use below code:

```
private void storeImage(Bitmap image) {
    try {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmm").format(new Date());
        String mImageName="MI_"+ timeStamp +".jpg";

        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(mImageName, MODE_PRIVATE);
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

it will save to data/data/your_packagename/files

Comment: your code didn't have problem, please check again, i think there are problem with your data or bitmap

Comment: i have a update for you, check it, i hope it can help you

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to save bitmap to internal storage.It will create dirctory in internal storage  `imageDir` , and you have to give the name to save your image i.e `profile.jpg`

```
 private String saveToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmapImage){
            ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
             // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
            File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            // Create imageDir
            File mypath=new File(directory,"profile.jpg");

            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {           
                fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
           // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
                bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                  fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } 
            return directory.getAbsolutePath();
        }
```

Comment: i have try this code. and still i can' t save a qrcode

Comment: can you check weather directory is created or not with your given name?